# Retrieve long Email subject lines using Exact Target API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have very long email subject lines already defined for Emails in Exact Target. When I try to extract the subject line using Exact Target WebService API, it is getting truncated. I am not able to extract the full subject line. Basically the subject lines are AMP scripts. e.g. One of my subject line is

```
%%[If LocaleId == "el" then]%%
some el string Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "vi" then]%%
some vi string Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "ca" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "it" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "eu" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory zerbitzura
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "cs" then]%%
cs string Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "et" then]%%
Tere tulemast teenusesse Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "gl" then]%%
Benvido(a) Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "id" then]%%
Selamat Datang di Direktori Aktif Windows Azure
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "es" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "no" then]%%
Welkom bij Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "tr" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory'ye Hoş Geldiniz
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "lv" then]%%
Laipni lūdzam pakalpojumā Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "lt" then]%%
lt string Windows Azure Active Directory“
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "ro" then]%%
Bun venit la Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "pl" then]%%
pl string Active Directory systemu Windows Azure
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "fr" then]%%
Bienvenue dans Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "ms" then]%%
Selamat datang ke Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "hr" then]%%
Dobro došli na uslugu Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "de" then]%%
Willkommen bei Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "da" then]%%
Velkommen til Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "hi" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory hindi
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "fi" then]%%
Tervetuloa Windows Azure Active 
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "kk" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory 
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "ko" then]%%
Windows Azure Active Directory 시작
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "sv" then]%%
Välkommen till Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "sk" then]%%
Vitajte v službe Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "pt-pt" then]%%
Bem-vindo ao Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "uk" then]%%
uk string Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "sl" then]%%
Dobrodošli v Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "pt-br" then]%%
Bem vindo(a) ao Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[else]%%
Welcome to Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[endif]%%
```

I am using the following code:

```
String requestID;
String status;
APIObject[] results;
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest{
    ObjectType = "Email",
    Properties =  new string[] { "Name", "ID", "Subject" }
};
SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart{
        Property = "Name",
        SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals,
        Value = "ActivationEmail"
};
rr.Filter = sfp;
soapClient.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
foreach (Email e in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " " + e.ID + " " + e.Subject);
}
```

With the above code, I get the partial subject line as:

```
%%[If LocaleId == "el" then]%%
some el string Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf LocaleId == "vi" then]%%
some vi string Windows Azure Active Directory
%%[elseIf Loc
```

What should I do to retrieve the full subject line via ?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that there is currently a limit on the retrieve to 200 characters for Subject.  One way to get around this would be to move the logic to the body of the email then reference a variable set in the body from the subject.

Example Subject:

```
%%=v(@Subject)=%%
```

In the Body, it would include block like the following that contains the logic for setting the @Subject variable:

```
%%[
If LocaleId == "el" then
set @Subject= "some el string Windows Azure Active Directory"
elseIf LocaleId == "vi" then
set @Subject= "some vi string Windows Azure Active Directory"
endif
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that the emails are already defined in Exact Target. I just need to retrieve the list of emails and their full subject lines. Is there a workaround for me to get this list ?

Comment: How to get this list ? I believe there should be some way for me to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation can only be described as "hack-tastic".  I would recommend you put all the (full) subject lines in a DE with one column, and use a "LIKE" lookup using the truncated subject line to get the full subject line.  Of course, this assumes the subject lines are different enough.  Hope this helps!